# IndexError: list index out of range using python

Tags: python

If i have 2 lists,
the first list
which has 100 values

```
listNum = list(range(1, 101))
```

the second list
which has 3 values

```
cars = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]
```

If i would like to add listNum values in next to cars which will be like this

```
for x in listNum:
    car = cars[x]
    print(cars)

output: Ford1, Volvo2
```

How can i do that?
I know I can make the loop like this,

```
for x in range(3):
```

But this is exhausting, i want to add a car without adjusting the loop range, every time I add a car I have to change the loop range

Comment: ```for x in range(len(cars)):``` you can use ```len``` of the lists and iterate over it

Comment: @Sujay But the numbers in the listNum list are not printed next to the cars `BMW1` `Volvo2`

Comment: Then you can use ```enumerate```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to implement this use case is to use `enumerate`:

```
for i, car in enumerate(cars, start=1):
    print(f'{car}{i}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is use `for x in range(len(cars)):`

The `len` function takes the number of characters or elements in the specified argument. This way, you won't need to update your loop manually.

```
for x in range(len(cars)):
    car = cars[x]
    print(car,x)
```

Here is the best solution

```
for x,y in enumerate(cars, start=1):
    print(x,y)
```

Comment: This is the output from you 2nd post: ```0 Ford
1 Volvo
2 BMW ```  - please verify your outputs with the PO expected outputs.

Comment: @DanielHao, ```enumerate``` starts from 0 by default